# MySql transpose multiple rows into column - the most optimized way for large data?

Tags: mysql, sql, transpose

i want to transpose multiple rows to column.

This my table with data (about 20 mil.rows)

```
PHONE      SERVICE
0000000    service1
0000000    service2
0000000    service3
1111111    service1
1111111    service4
2222222    service5
```

and I would like to get the following output:

```
PHONE      SC1       SC2       SC3       SC4   SC5
0000000    service1  service2  service3  NULL  NULL
1111111    service1  service4  NULL      NULL  NULL
2222222    service5  NULL      NULL      NULL  NULL
```

etc..

Anybody know the fastest to do this (for about 20mil records)? Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you really need them in separate columns? `GROUP_CONCAT` won't work for you?

Comment: Are you *sure* that is a good way to transform the data? The desired end result does not look useful to RA itself. And if it's in an application the application can handle cleanup. A better "goal" might be to get to `(phone,service,service_index)`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work well, make sure you have an index on `phone`.

```
SELECT phone,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(services, ',', 1) SC1,
       if(service_count >= 2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(services, ',', 2), ',', -1), NULL) SC2,
       if(service_count >= 3, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(services, ',', 3), ',', -1), NULL) SC3,
       if(service_count >= 4, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(services, ',', 4), ',', -1), NULL) SC4,
       if(service_count >= 5, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(services, ',', 5), ',', -1), NULL) SC5
FROM (SELECT phone, GROUP_CONCAT(service) AS services, COUNT(*) as service_count
      FROM phones
      GROUP BY phone) AS x
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10618/1)

Comment: thanks Barmar for your quick response, i did not ta iclearly state that data in 'SERVICE' column can by of any value , not necessarily beging witn service*

Comment: My answer doesn't depend on that. The only problem would be if it can contain `,` characters. You'll need to change the separator in `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to something that isn't in the values.

Comment: I've changed my demo to use more random service strings.

Comment: currently 'PHONE' is VARCHAR not INT. and i got the following error:
Error

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'SELECT phone, GROUP_CONCAT(service) AS services, COUNT(*) as service_count
    ' at line 7

Comment: My answer doesn't care what datatype `phone` is. I don't get that error, you must have copied something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to number the services within each group and use conditional aggregation to pivot your rows into columns.

```
select phone,
    max(case when rn = 1 then service end) sc1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then service end) sc2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then service end) sc3,
    max(case when rn = 4 then service end) sc4,
    max(case when rn = 5 then service end) sc5
from (
    select phone,service,
      @rowNum := if(@prevPhone = phone,@rowNum+1,1) rn, 
      @prevPhone := phone
    from mytable 
    cross join (select @prevPhone := null, @rowNum := 1) c 
    order by phone, service
) t1 group by phone
```