# SQL Average of fields based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, reporting

I am creating a reporting tool and it has a specific requirement I would like to solve in the SQL world. I am using MySQL 5.6.11:
We have some inputs that can be introduced none, one or twice a day:

```
DATETIME            | VALUE

01-01-2015 00:10:11 |   5 
01-03-2015 00:11:11 |   3
01-03-2015 00:12:11 |   4
01-03-2015 00:11:11 |   5
01-03-2015 00:12:11 |   8
```

I would like to get the average of the values the following way:

```
DATETIME   | FIRST INSERTED VALUE AVERAGE | SECOND INSERTED VALUE AVERAGE
01-01-2015 |          5                   | null
01-03-2015 |          4                   | 6
```

We are interested on having the average of all the records, but the time is important.
We want the average of the first value introduced that specific day for all the reports in a column and the average of the second introduced values (if any) on the second.

This is an example of one report without considering the difference between the first and the second value

```
SELECT AVG(bt.value), DATE(bt.date) 
    FROM reports bt
    GROUP BY DATE(bt.date)
```

Comment: how are you exactly intending to do the calculation? ok value average = sum of numbers / total numbers which means 5 to value 1 in first record and second it must be 4, but yours say 3 ,and how are the second_value average calculated? please elaborate what you are trying to do..

Comment: You have to explan what is first and second value average

Comment: Just edited it with more explanations. Thanks!

Comment: still dont understand why you are calling it average, from your representations it seems nothing but the first and second value in order it has been added

Comment: @Ammadu you are right, it wasn't obvious, I just updated the example

Comment: avg for 01-03-2015 is 5(20(sum  of numbers on 1-3)/4(number of transcation). so i cant proper getting youpr point.

Comment: That is the point, I want to get the average of the first introduced value in one field and the average of the second introduced value in other one.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather hard to perform transposition operations like this, but I think you can get what you want by using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

First, you have to group the results by the full DATETIME, and then you can group again by the DATE part, while concatenating the results in the averages column. The final SELECT will parse the concatenated string into different columns.

```
SELECT date, SUBSTRING_INDEX(averages, '#', 1) FIRST,
   if (averages_count >= 2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(averages, '#', 2), '#', -1), NULL) SECOND

FROM (SELECT DATE(derived.date) AS date, GROUP_CONCAT(derived.average SEPARATOR '#') AS averages, COUNT(*) AS averages_count
          FROM (SELECT bt.date AS date, AVG(bt.value) AS average
                    FROM reports AS bt
                    GROUP BY bt.date) AS derived
          GROUP BY DATE(date)) AS base
```

(I got my inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27576065/4751173)).

Comment: Actually this is not doing it completely right.It is not calculating the proper averages of the second type.